# How can I change my product's currency based on the IP address in woocommerce in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How should I modify the code of a website to change the currency by IP address?

I tried too many plugins for changing the currency based on the IP address, but it's not working properly. I need some custom code or a plug-in to solve this problem.

Can anyone provide some?

Comment: [WooCommerce Price Based on Country](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-price-based-on-countries/) Here's a plugin

Comment: How many countries are you selling to ?

Answer (score 0):

This is also a third party api. I'm not sure about the accuracy of this but give it a try.

http://usercountry.com/

Using that we get the current currency. Then you can set currency dynamically with the below plugin hooks.

https://aelia.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/3000010676-how-to-change-the-selected-currency-via-code

```
function set_currency_programmatically($selected_currency) {
  // Use the usercountry api here to find the currency.
  $selected_currency = 'USD';

  return $selected_currency;
}
add_filter('wc_aelia_cs_selected_currency', 'set_currency_programmatically', 0);
```